# Selenium cannot interact with an already open Google Chrome window when running on a remote server

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm trying to connect selenium to an already open Google Chrome window in the following way:

```
options.add_experimental_option('debuggerAddress', 'localhost:9112')
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')
options.add_argument('--disable-browser-side-navigation')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('enable-automation')
self.d = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\chromedriver.exe', options=options)
```

By first calling Google Chrome from the command line:

```
chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=9112 --user-data-dir="C:\selenum\AutomationProfile"
```

At first it's working fine, driver does his thing, but as soon as I logged out of the server and, of course, can't see browser window, Selenium also stops seeing it and raising errors

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable (Session info: chrome=105.0.5195.102)
no such window: target window already closed from unknown error: web view not found (Session info: chrome=105.0.5195.102)
```

The interesting thing is that when I switch back to the remote machine, the browser loads and continues to work.
I also tried to add

```
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
```

But it didn't solve the problem. When I run selenium in normal way without command line, debugging and other stuff then it works stable, but I need to handle an already opened Google Chrome window.

Comment: I can assume its an windows machine? If this is correct, it can be the lock screen.
When the tests is running - screen is locked, when you login - screen unlocks and you see everything fine.
If this is not the case, can you provide more information about the whole setup.

Comment: @Infern0
Yes, it is Windows-Server 2016. Is it possible to put the lockscreen into the unlock state forever?

Comment: Hi @Boris, its quite a hack-ish way to make the RDP to stay active - actually the display.
There is a multiple topics - how and where to edit the registry for this.
I think there is an already such topic before years, where i also gave an example.
Will try to link it here.

Comment: One possible solution - https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/testing-with/running/via-rdp/keeping-computer-unlocked.html
I am sure there is an solution to keep the display active or the session trough the windows registries.

Comment: Thank you @Infern0. So the problem is that the lock screen is blocking the execution of the python script?

Comment: if the tests is not failing with the error message above when you are connected trough RDP to the remote machine, and only fails while you sign-out, one of the possible issues is the one i explained above.
If you are getting the same issue while connected, its obviously something else.
So provide as much info as possible, what/where/when.

Comment: Got it. Everything works exactly as you described - errors occur after disconnecting from the server.

Comment: Glad to help, the link above can guide you how to "workaround" the issue, but for sure there is much more robust solution trough registry. 
Try work with the IT team for this.